# operator % is not working for null values

Tags: plsql, null, operator-keyword

Assume the customer table is as follows.

```
cust_id  |  name  |   address | language
A        |   AAA  |      ZZZZ |      en
B        |   BBB  |      YYYY |      
C        |   CCC  |      XXXX |      pl
D        |   DDD  |      WWWW |      en
```

I want to get a plsql code that will accept user input for the language filed, and when user input;

```
1. 'en'; cust_id: A,B should be the result
2. 'pl'; cust_id: C should be the result
3. doesnt input a value;  cust_id: A,B,C,D should be the result

select cust_id from customer c where c.language like NVL('&lang','%');
```

option 1 & 2 works fine with the above query, but 3 doesnt result any value. I think it is because % operator is not working with null values. can anyone help me to revise the query which is capable of giving results for all the 3 options?

Comment: `%` works with a `like` operator, here you just compare `A == %?`. This wont work. You could simply compare to `c.language` in case of `&A` beeing null.

Comment: i have edited the query using 'like'. But still it doesnt give me the intended output for my 3rd question.

Comment: You´re getting more results? theoretically you should get `A`, `C` and `D`. `B` wouldn´t be shown as `null` is not like any value and needs a seperate `null` check, or another separate `nvl` for `&lang` and `language` beeing null.

Comment: Actually what I need is if user doesnt input anything all the records should be fetched, if user specifically input a value query should give the intended result for that input. Any idea on how o do that?

Comment: I don't see any [PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info) here. This looks like a plain SQL question.

Comment: I add this question as plsql, since there can be keywords which can be suggested and if so those should be compatible for plsql. since i m using oracle plsql.

Comment: [`plsql`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info) tag description: _PL/SQL (Procedural Language/Structured Query Language) is Oracle Corporation's procedural language extension for SQL. Questions about PL/SQL should probably be tagged "oracle" as well. Questions with regular DML or DDL statements should be tagged with "sql" and "oracle", NOT with "plsql"._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this with `or`:

```
with customer (cust_id, name, address, language) as
     ( select 'A', 'AAA', 'ZZZZ', 'en' from dual union all
       select 'B', 'BBB', 'YYYY', null from dual union all
       select 'C', 'CCC', 'XXXX', 'pl' from dual union all
       select 'D', 'DDD', 'WWWW', 'en' from dual )
select * from customer c
where  (c.language = '&lang' or '&lang' is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a decode, as shown in the below example:

```
select *
from (select 'en' col1 from dual union all
      select 'en' from dual union all
      select 'pl' from dual union all
      select null from dual) dummy
where decode('&lang', col1, 1, -- If lang is not null and equals col1, return 1, this will only select raws where lang = col1
                      null, 1,    -- if lang is null return 1, this will select every raw
                            2)  = 1 -- Default equals 2 for everything not fitting col1, will only be used if lang is not null
```

O/P lang = en:

```
en
en
```

O/P lang = en:

```
pl
```

O/P lang is null:

```
en
en
pl
"null"
```

Your select should be looking like this from the example above:

```
select cust_id 
from customer c 
where decode('&lang', col1, 1, 
                      null, 1, 
                            2)  = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query:

```
select cust_id from customer c where c.language = NVL('&lang', c.language);
```

When `&lang` is `null` query will return all the rows from `customer` table.